# Periodically sending a message from java server to android device under wifi

Tags: java, android, networking, message-passing

I had to develop an android app to send a file from an android device to a PC which under the same WiFi(only local, no internet) for a work. For that I made the PC as a server and running a client program from the android phone. That part is working fine. Now I need to have some message passing mechanism at the server, which will periodically send some update messages to the android device, based on which I will update few flag variables in the android device. Can anyone tell me in what approach I should solve this? Also the message passing can happen at certain intervals of time or at the initiation of the communication. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah - the no internet problem changes things. You should be able to create a service to run on the device that listens to commands on a certain port. Then construct a server app that writes commands to that port

Comment: Ok. So you are telling that I should create a seperate service on the android device to listen to a particular port and my server application in the pc would send the message to that port. Will it be possible for me to pass the received information at the service to my actual file transfer client app in android? Thanks

Comment: Yes - when the service receives a command from the server you can fire an intent at your app, relaying the message to the actual app. The advantage of a service over an app as the port listener is that the service will always be running, where an app is not guaranteed to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was thinking about using a service but not sure about its advantages over app. Was facing thread related problems. I will try with service and let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Socket Programming for this purpose by which you can send string or files from your pc/laptop  to android device (condition is that they both form local network (may be wired or wireless)).

Comment: I have already tried that approach but there was some concurrency issues that was facing and the application crashed several times. I want some better approach to handle that.

Comment: You can give a try to RMI but I don't know much about that, I am using socket for my project and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [google cloud messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) it is a mechanism to pass messages between a server and an android client. Basically you would subscribe to a particular key from the client and then your server will push a message with that token to Google's cloud messaging server and it will relay the message to any phone that is subscribed to it. This is the standard way of pushing messages from a server to an android client and abstracts away a lot of low level functionality.